# Load XML file from HDFS in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to load a XML file from HDFS using XML Scala API. I am trying as follows but its not recognizing the path. Could anyone let me know how we can load file from HDFS by using Scala?

```
import scala.xml.{NodeSeq, XML}

val xml_load = XML.loadFile("hdfs:////user/np.user/raw/xmlfile.xml")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using Scala 2.12.x; I also assume those four slashes in `hdfs:////user...` are typo.

You're using method `XML.loadFile(name: String)`; it internally uses `FileInputStream`. It's not possible to open an HDFS file with a plain `FileInputStream`. You need an input stream which supports HDFS. You can find it in `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs` library.

The code then looks like this:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
// configure properly so the code knows which Hadoop cluster to connect to
// https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html
val conf = new Configuration()

// obtain input stream instance
val hdfsPath: Path = new Path("hdfs://user/np.user/raw/xmlfile.xml")
val fs: FileSystem = hdfsPath.getFileSystem(conf)
val inputStream: FSDataInputStream = fs.open(hdfsPath)
// load XML
try {
  val xml_load = XML.load(inputStream)
} finally {
  // close resources; of course, this will silently swallow any exception in close() methods 
  inputStream.close()
  fs.close()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and I am using scala 2.11 and you are right about hdfs path(typo). When I am trying to get file system, its not recognizing path -- val fs: FileSystem = path.getFileSystem(conf). Am  I missing some library to include?

Comment: I thing if I use FileSystem.get(conf), it works. Also if I want to read multiple files from the folder hdfs://user/np.user/raw/, how do we read them? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Babu yeah, sorry, there was a typo. I defined the variable as `hdfsPath`, but then referenced it just as `path`. I fixed the example.

Comment: @Babu well there is `listFiles` method on `FileSystem` https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listFiles-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-boolean-; it returns a `RemoteIterator[LocatedFileStatus]` which you can iterate over and obtain a `Path` from the `FileStatus` with `getPath` method.